# How to get value from another Class in Java which does not contain void main?

Tags: java, swing

I have three classes as follows:

-OnePa (it contains public static void main())
-New
-Choose
Under the same package.

I want to get the value of "string name" which is declared and stored in New.java
**from Choose.java**

```
 package com.ash;

  import javax.swing.JFrame;

   public class New1 extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4648531955064052430L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_3;
private JFormattedTextField textField_2;
private JComboBox comboBox;
String FNm;
String LNm;

Connection con;
Choose CT11=new Choose();



//Mask-Formatter is created
protected MaskFormatter createFormatter(String s){
    MaskFormatter formatter=null;
    try{
        formatter=new MaskFormatter(s);
    }catch(java.text.ParseException exc){
        System.err.println("formatter is bad:"+exc.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return formatter;
}



public New1() {
    setTitle("New ");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 585, 415);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("First Name");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 13));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(40, 62, 91, 28);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last Name");
    lblLastName.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 13));
    lblLastName.setBounds(40, 101, 91, 28);
    contentPane.add(lblLastName);



    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(150, 66, 146, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(150, 105, 146, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);



    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Next >>");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(150, 289, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);



    ImageIcon home = new ImageIcon("D:\\Source AP\\home.jpg");
    JButton HomeButton = new JButton(home);
    HomeButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {


            textField.setText(null);
            textField_1.setText(null);
            textField_2.setText(null);
            textField_3.setText(null);

            dispose();

        }
    });
    HomeButton.setBounds(26, 289, 45, 38);
    contentPane.add(HomeButton);





    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            //Storing Values in String
            GetValues();

            label.setVisible(false);
            label_1.setVisible(false);
            label_2.setVisible(false);
            label_3.setVisible(false);
            lblNewLabel_1.setVisible(false);

            if((FNm.length()==0 || FNm.trim().length()==0)||

                          (LNm.length()==0 || LNm.trim().length()==0)))
            {
                System.out.println("It is blank or contains white
                                   spaces");

            }
            else{

            System.out.println("Success");


                //Connection

                try {
                con=DbConnPa.getConObj();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                DbConnPa.Reg1(con, FNm, LNm, Age, RefDoc, Sex);
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            CT11.setVisible(true);

            //hides the current JFrame
            dispose();
            }

        }
    });

}
public void GetValues(){
    FNm=textField.getText();
    LNm=textField_1.getText();

}


     }
```

Choose.java:

```
package com.ash;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Choose extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1946720589313613447L;
private JPanel contentPane;




int i=0;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Choose frame = new Choose();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */

public Choose() {
    setTitle("Choose ");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 910, 516);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Next >>");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(39, 396, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Hello");
    checkBox.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 13));
    checkBox.setBounds(39, 120, 132, 23);
    contentPane.add(checkBox);

    JLabel lblFirstName = new JLabel("First Name :");
    lblFirstName.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 13));
    lblFirstName.setBounds(39, 11, 82, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblFirstName);

    JLabel lblLastName = new JLabel("Last Name :");
    lblLastName.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 13));
    lblLastName.setBounds(39, 34, 82, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblLastName);

    JLabel Ctname = new JLabel();
    Ctname.setBounds(131, 12, 132, 16);
    contentPane.add(Ctname);

    JLabel Ctlst = new JLabel();
    Ctlst.setBounds(131, 35, 132, 16);
    contentPane.add(Ctlst);
    contentPane.add(Ctref);
    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            //if Chk1 is selected it will return TRUE else FALES.
            Boolean afb=checkBox.isSelected();

            if(afb== true)
                {
                System.out.println("Is selected");
                }
        }
    });
}
          }
```

Comment: The code of these three classes is too long.

Comment: this is simple.google it, you can find it easily.

Comment: Google showed me to do
anotherclass Name=new anotherclass();
then access it as string n1=anotherclass.name;

bt this giving me error

Comment: What is the relationship between New.java and Choose.java?

Comment: They are in same package com.ash
and i created the object of Choose.java in New.java already.
But unable to create object of New.java in Choose.java

Comment: If you are creating Choose inside New, then why not pass the name in the constructor of Choose and then you have the variable.

Comment: I didnt get you Byron.

Comment: Please stop using `null`-layout and calling `setBounds`. Use appropriate LayoutManager's instead.

Comment: Then what should I use instead?
But please tell me solution of my question that i asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method in `Choose.java` called `public void setName(String name)`, then when you call `GetValues()` in New.java pass the variable FNm to `Choose.java` as follows: `CT11.setName(FNm)`. Now you have passed the name to the choose class where you can store it in a global variable and do with it what you please.

Comment: The Fm in CT11.setName(Fm) should be declared in New.java or in the method public void SetName() ?

Comment: I was referring to the variable you already have `FNm=textField.getText();`.

Comment: I am new to java so asking so many questions. sorry for that

I did it but how to get that value in Choose.java?
i created 
    public void setName(String Ctname){
    system.out.println(Ctname);
    }
but unable to print it

Answer (score 0):

Most likely from a method or constructor in `Choose.java`.

`main()` is just like any other method in java, except for one thing - at runtime, it is used by jvm to find an entry point to the application.

So if you know how to access the field from `main()`, you can *most likely* access the variable using the same approach from any other method given that the field itself or any of it's accessors is [accessible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: When I am creating object of New.java in Choose.java it showing error of init();

Comment: at com.ash.Choose.<init>(Choose.java:22) this type of error is showing near about 20-30 times